# Is there a better way to run multiple SQL queries to the same table using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a query that requests an ID (the PK) and an order number and throws them into an array. I then loop through the returned data in the array and run two more queries to find the number of times the order number shows up in the database and to get the invoice numbers that belong to that order number. The problem I'm seeing with this setup is that it is taking a while (around 9 seconds) to return the compiled data array. Is there a faster way to get the returned results I'm looking for?

I've tried to find some articles online and came across [mysqli_multi_query](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_multi_query.asp). Is this the better route to make multiple queries to gather the type of data I am trying to get?

```
<?php
    require 'config.php';
    $sql = "SELECT id,internal_order_number FROM orders GROUP BY internal_order_number ORDER BY created_date desc LIMIT 0 ,50";
    $query=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
    if (!$query) {
        throw new Exception(mysqli_error($mysqli)."[ $sql]");
    }
    $data = array();
    while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {  // preparing an array
      $nestedData=array();
      $nestedData['line_id'] = $row["id"];
      $nestedData['internal_order_number'] = $row["internal_order_number"];
      $data[] = $nestedData;
    }
    $compiled_data = array();

    // Loop through data array with additional queries
    foreach($data as $line){
      $new_data = array();

      // Get item counts
      $item_counts = array();
      $get_count = " SELECT internal_order_number FROM orders WHERE internal_order_number = '".$line['internal_order_number']."' ";
      $count_query=mysqli_query($mysqli, $get_count);
      while ($counts=mysqli_fetch_array($count_query)){
        if (isset($item_counts[$counts['internal_order_number']])) {
          $item_counts[$counts['internal_order_number']]++;
        } else {
          $item_counts[$counts['internal_order_number']] = 1;
        }
      }
      $product_count = $item_counts[$line['internal_order_number']];

      // Get invoice numbers
      $invoice_array = array();
      $get_invoices = " SELECT invoice_number FROM orders WHERE internal_order_number = '".$line['internal_order_number']."'";
      $invoice_query=mysqli_query($mysqli, $get_invoices);
      while ($invoice=mysqli_fetch_array($invoice_query)){
        if(!in_array($invoice['invoice_number'], $invoice_array)){
          $invoice_array[] = $invoice['invoice_number'];
        }
      }
      $invoices = implode(", ",$invoice_array);

      $new_data['order_number'] = $line['internal_order_number'];
      $new_data['count'] = $product_count;
      $new_data['invoices'] = $invoices;
      $compiled_data[] = $new_data;
    }
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
    print_r($compiled_data);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What, why are you doing basically the same query 3 times. You first one selects them all, you second query requires the same table making sure the first tables order number == the tables order number and the last just grabs the invoice number...?

Just do one query:

```
SELECT internal_order_number, invoice_number FROM table WHERE ...
```

Then loop through it and do what you need. You don't need 3 queries...

Comment: You are absolutely right, looping through the data in the initial query was all I needed to do. Thank you!